# How to get type 'NoneType' to print out as a string to an external file? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, logging, stdout, nonetype, stringio

I have a datalib method that is type 'NoneType' and it behaves oddly:

```
>>> print ISC_MSG
None
>>> ISC_MSG = (ISC.message("INFO", MESSAGE = 'test' ))
INFO                 (I) test
>>> ISC_MSG
>>>
```

I'd like to print "INFO   (I) test" to an external file, but every time I try a 'print' or file.write()...it gives me "None."

How might I get this StringIO() to print the actual content in string format "INFO (I) test" to a file?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `ISC`? It looks like the method prints the message and returns `None`. Look at the `ISC` API and see if it offers a way to return the message instead of printing it. I notice that there is no `StringIO` in your example, how is it involved?

Comment: ISC is a datalib. Kind of like SQL.